# μTorrent doesn't seed/download when 2 peers

Tags: download, bittorrent, utorrent, upload

I am today in Germany and decided to transfer 1,5 Gb of photos to my home computer. Both PCs are using Windows, both have μTorrent. Why not direct upload through VPN? Because the German upload speed is too low and connection is unstable. μTorrent helps me to transfer data in small chunks.

My home computer has a public IP address, I opened a port there and turned the μTorrent's tracker on.

In Germany I created torrent, added my home tracker to it and started seeding. Then I transfered torrent file to my home PC and started downloading.

At the beginning everything was Ok. My home collection started to grow slowly, but then something happened and data is not transfered anymore. Either one μTorrent doesn't want to seed or other μTorrent does not want to download.

What could happen? I suppose that upload/download ratio could be involved but am unsure.

I use VPN to my home network. Other services work through this VPN flawlessly. If it were a setup problem, then I would not able to download anything even at the very begin.

**Update**

I made an one hour pause, then connected VPN and started the seeding μTorrent, and it seeds!

Comment: Its most likely an issue with your setup, however, ISPs hate torrents and frequently throttle or block them. Try changing your ports.

Comment: I use VPN to my home network. Other services work through this VPN flawlessly. If it were a setup problem, then I would not able to download anything even at the very begin.

Answer (score 0):

I know you were specifically looking for information on using μTorrent to transfer files, but here me out.  If you're using Windows (Vista or higher), then there should be a built in program called Robocopy available to you.  Robocopy is capable of transferring files over networks, and might be worth your while.  When it detects that the transfer has stopped, it will make several attempts, (the default is set to 1 million retries waiting 30 seconds in between attempts), to continue transferring the file(s).  You can also make it wait a certain amount of time before sending packets to the destination as well, which basically limits the transfer speed if desired.  It's very flexible and could be exactly what you need to transfer your files.

Personally, I wouldn't use the tracker option you have set up right now as it's a potential security risk, not to mention anyone that sniffs your traffic would be able to see all of the pictures you're trying to sync.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Robocopy could be an option, but, as I think, Torrent has some advantages. One of them is that I can interrupt transfer at any moment, turn the computer off and continue in the next day. All the pratially transferred files remain partially transferred. And I believe that VPN protects me from sniffing (ok, there could exist a MITM attack, but I am not so paranoid).